# How to insert array if pass is value

Tags: php

```
<?php
$test1 ="pass";
$test2 = "fail";
$test3 = "pass";
$check = array();
        for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
            if($test1== "pass"){
                $num = 1;
            }
            if($test2 == "pass"){
                $num = 2;
            }
            if($test3 == "pass"){
                $num = 3;
            }

            echo $num;
            $check[$i] = $num;
        }
?>
```

value: test1="pass",test2="fail",test3="pass"

I want: $check(1,3)

Take only the "pass"

I want to put a value equal to "pass" in the array. The condition is that the value must be equal to "pass". 
but test1,test2,test3 not array.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. How would you want to use this code in a real scenario?

Comment: Not clear to understand your question

Comment: I want to put a value equal to "pass" in the array. The condition is that the value must be equal to "pass".

Comment: Please provide your wanted output.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are looking for this:

```
$test1 = "pass";
$test2 = "fail";
$test3 = "pass";
$check = array();

for($i = 1; $i <=3; $i++) {
    $t  =   'test'.$i;
    if(${$t} == 'pass')
        $check[]    =   $i;
}

print_r($check);
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)
```

It's somewhat difficult to tell, but if so, this uses [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), cutting down on some script when using sequential variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like :

```
$test1 ="pass";
$test2 = "fail";
$test3 = "pass";
$check = array();
$num = '';

if($test1== "pass"){
    $num .= '1,';
}

if($test2 == "pass"){
    $num .= '2,';
}

if($test3 == "pass"){
    $num .= '3,';
}

$num = trim($num,',');
$check = explode(',',$num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test1 ="pass";
$test2 = "fail";
$test3 = "pass";    
$num =array();

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    if($test1 == "pass"){
        $num[] = 1;                
    }

    if($test2 == "pass"){
        $num[] = 2;
    }

    if($test3 == "pass"){
        $num[] = 3;
    }
}

print_r(array_unique($num));
```